# Show forward substitution for triangular matrix is backward stable

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose $L$ is a lower triangular matrix and that $Lx=b$ is solved by forward substitution. Show the computed solution $\hat{x}$ satisfies $(L+\delta L)\hat{x}=b$, where $|\delta l_{ij}|\leq n\epsilon |l_{ij}|$, where $\epsilon$ is machine precision.

Just point me in how to get started on the problem, I think I can take it from there. I have some ideas, but I'm not too sure if it's what the question is asking for, i.e. using the fact that $fl(a\bigodot b)=(a\bigodot b)(1+\delta)$ and obtain the bound from there

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, you need another equation and your exact goal is not necessarily possible.

---

The standard model for floating point arithmetic is usually stated as
$$ \text{fl}(a \odot b) = (a \odot b)(1+\delta),$$
where $|\delta| \leq u$ and $u$ is the unit roundoff. This single expression is not sufficient here as seen in the case of the scalar equation
$$ l_{11} x_1 = b_1.$$
The computed value $\hat{x}_1$ of $x_1 = b_1/l_{11}$ satisfies
$$ \hat{x}_1 = \frac{b_1}{l_{11}}(1+\delta)$$
for some $\delta$ with $|\delta| \leq u$. It follows that $\hat{x}_1$ satisfies the scalar equation
$$ \frac{1}{1+\delta} l_{11} \hat{x}_1 = b_1 $$
This is very nearly an expression of the type that is sought, but it is not quite good enough, because
$$ \frac{1}{1+\delta} = 1 - \delta + \delta^2 - \delta^3 + \dotsc.$$
We can certainly define $$ \nu = \sum_{j=1}^\infty (-\delta)^j$$ and write
$$(1 + \nu) l_{11} \hat{x}_1 = b_1$$
but we cannot have
$$ |\nu| \leq u$$
because that is simply not true in general. Instead it is necessary to recognize that the floating point representation of a real number $x$ not only satisfies 
$$ \text{fl}(x) = x(1+\delta), \quad |\delta| \leq u$$
but also
$$ \text{fl}(x) = \frac{x}{1 + \xi} \quad |\xi| \leq u.$$
These two expressions do not follow from one another, but they can be derived from scratch using the same reasoning. Returning to the case of our scalar equation, the second variant yields
$$ \hat{x}_1 = \frac{b_1}{l_{11}} \frac{1}{1 + \xi}.$$
We see that the computed value of $x_1$ satisfies the perturbed equation
$$ (1 + \xi) l_{11} \hat{x}_1 = b_1, \quad |\xi| \leq u.$$
In the general case of a lower triangular system with more than single equation it is necessary to use both variants of the standard model of floating point computation. I do not know that the stated bound for the component backward error is actually true, but you can obtain a slightly weaker bound, namely
$$ |\Delta l_{ij}| \leq \gamma_{n} |l_{ij}|, \quad \gamma_n = \frac{nu}{1-nu}$$
The entire analysis is written out in Chapter 3 of Higham's book: "Accuracy and stability of numerical algorithms".